# Slack Admin Invite API not sending invite

Tags: slack-api

I am using slack users.admin.invite and it is working fine. 
But for one domain xxx@mailinator.com it is not working. 
The response is : invite_failed

Is this domain is blacklisted by slack or some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

That is likely. In my experience some email domains are indeed not working with [`user.admin.invite`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md). And since this is an undocumented API method, it will not be possible to get any support from the Slack team for it.

I would suggest to user manual invites for these cases.